# Haystack: one searchIndex for multiple models

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

On the [getting started page](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) of Haystack, it describes the possibility of using one SearchIndex for multple models:

> You generally create a unique SearchIndex for each type of Model you
>   wish to index, though you can reuse the same SearchIndex between
>   different models if you take care in doing so and your field names are
>   very standardized.

However I haven't found any information regarding how to do so. The reasoning behind it is that a few Heroku search engine apps provide limited amount of indices, so I think it's a good idea to keep the number of indices slim. How should I do it?

Comment: I think this reffers to the fact that you can define one Index class that would be usable with several models. You would still register each model separately and haystack would still create a different index for each one, though.

Comment: Be careful about confusing `SearchIndex` classes with indexes in the search engine. Haystack's `SearchIndex` is defining a type of search document to index. If a service like [SearchBox](https://addons.heroku.com/searchbox) for example restricts you to one index, I don't think the number of `SearchIndex` classes you define is going to impact the number of indices.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! So do I have control over how many indices it will create?

Answer (score 0):

No of index will be one only unless you specify in setting.py .Multiple search_index.py files doesnot mean that multiple indexes.