# Django Haystack - A SearchIndex Based on Multiple Models

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have some problems by trying to create my SearchIndex with Haystack on Django and I don't know what to do.

**Here are my two models**:

```
# Meta: stores meta data about tutorials (category, title)
class Meta(models.Model):
    """
    Database [tutorial.meta]
    """
    mta_title = models.CharField(max_length=TUTORIAL_TITLE_MAX)
    mta_views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)


# Contents: stores the tutorial text content
class Contents(models.Model):
    """
    Database [tutorial.contents]
    """
    tut_id = IdField()
    cnt_body = BBCodeTextField()
```

Now I want to base my SearchIndex on the 3 following fields: mta_title, mta_views and cnt_body. Here are my current SearchIndex:

```
from haystack import indexes
from tutorial.models import Meta as TutorialMeta
from account.models import Profile as UserProfile


class TutorialMetaIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='mta_title')
    views = indexes.CharField(model_attr='mta_views')
    # Haystack reserves the content field names for internal use
    cnt_body = indexes.CharField()

    def get_model(self):
        return TutorialMeta

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def prepare_cnt_body(self, obj):
        ????
```

I've seen [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170537/haystack-one-searchindex-for-multiple-models), that the answer was to create a prepare_cnt_body. But I don't know what I should return.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Sectio Aurea,

But here is my solution with a simple prepare function:

```
class TutorialIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    """
    Index the tutorials
    """
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    tut_id = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='tut_id')
    cnt_body = indexes.CharField(model_attr='cnt_body')
    mta_title = indexes.CharField()
    mta_views = indexes.CharField()

    def get_model(self):
        """
        Return the current model
        """
        return TutorialContents

    def get_updated_field(self):
        """
        Return the update date tracking field
        """
        return "cnt_date"

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """
        Used when the entire index for model is updated.
        """
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def prepare(self, object):
        """
        Prepare the search data
        """
        self.prepared_data = super(TutorialIndex, self).prepare(object)

        # Retrieve the tutorial metas and return the prepared data
        meta = get_tutorial_meta(id=object.tut_id)
        self.prepared_data['mta_title'] = meta.mta_title
        self.prepared_data['mta_views'] = meta.mta_views

        return self.prepared_data
```

Comment: Interesting. Which Django version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

No need for 'prepare'. Simply use the template you've referred to in your 'text' field. In your app 'myapp', create the file templates/search/indexes/myapp/tutorialmeta_text.txt. In this file create the following entries using standard Django template language model references, something like:

```
{{object.mta_title}}
{{object.mta_views}}
{{object.contents.cnt_body}}
```

Then you'll need to rebuild your index with the new template (./manage.py rebuild_index). This will index each of the three referred fields against each object. With this method, you can also omit the 'title', 'views' and 'cnt_body' fields from your SearchIndex class, as well as the 'prepare' method.