# Django Haystack Foreign key Search result specific result

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am building a Question and Answer solution using Django 
The answer Model has foriegn key to question

When implementing search ,I want it to be like quora's default search where the query searched is found both in question and also if the query is present in any of the answers to the question it is displayed below the question.

So basically how do I build search Index template?

If I create a document template with all the answer body

```
class QuestionIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    created_at = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='created_at')

    def get_model(self):
        return Question
```

with question document Template as

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.body }}
{% for answer in object.answers %}
   {{answer.body}}
{% endfor %}
```

In the view how do I get the specific answer object for which match is found?

Or should I create seperate index for answer?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Django-Haystack. But you could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926878/django-haystack-a-searchindex-based-on-multiple-models) as it shows how to create a search index with multiple models at the same time.